# JComboBox, set space between choices

Tags: java, touch, jcombobox

I have created a program that will be used on both computer and tablet. The problem is that the options that come up when you press the JComboboxes becomes very small on the tablet. How can you with ease get a small gap between the options? Or are there other alternative solutions to address this problem?
Thanks for all your help and contributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define your own list cell renderer for the combo box, and have that custom renderer provide padding on all four sides.

Here's a small program showing how. While you can't literally put spaces between the items in the list, the list renderer will allow you to put padding around the data item in the list, which should make it easier to select. setBorder() is where you'd vary your padding if you want more or less.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;


class CustomComboBoxRenderer extends JTextField implements ListCellRenderer
{
public CustomComboBoxRenderer()
{
    this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder( this.getBorder(), 
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(15, 0, 10, 0)));
}


@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
        int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
    if (isSelected) {
        setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
        setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
    } else {
        setBackground(list.getBackground());
        setForeground(list.getForeground());
    }
    this.setText(value.toString());
    return this;
}

}
public class Gui extends JFrame{

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
String[] data = new String[]{"A","B","C","D","E","F"};
ComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(data);
JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(model);
CustomComboBoxRenderer renderer = new CustomComboBoxRenderer();

public  Gui()
{
    combo.setRenderer(renderer);
    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    content.add(combo);
    setContentPane(content);
    pack();
    setLocation(300,300);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Gui();
}

}
```

Comment: That just might work. Do you have an example of how to do that? @swingMan

Comment: Fantastic! This is awesome! Now I have something to play with tonight! ;) Thanks @swingMan